# can you explain the error

Tags: sentence-construction

This question was asked in my examination and the answer is: there is an error in **(3)**. can you explain why?

> If you inform me of Kanika's<sup>(1)</sup> /arrival time I shall go to<sup>(2)</sup> /attend  her at the airport<sup>(3)</sup> /no error<sup>(4)</sup>

I am really baffled.

Comment: Perhaps because "her" would be an indirect object of attend.  So would be more correct "attend to her", though "wait" would be the verb better suited there.

Comment: I guess the error is indeed that you do not _attend_ someone; in French you do (il attend sa copine) but in English you _wait for_ someone, or possibly, you _await_ someone_. You could go and _attend to_ her.

Comment: You attend (to) the sick (either transitive or intransitive), but it is always intransitive when you have to be at a scheduled event: "you attend to her at the airport."

Answer (score 1):

I believe (and I'm ready to be corrected) we do not attend to people explicitly in [vernacular] English any more but it is possible to attend to a personage. for instance

- Attend to the Mayor's requirements.
- Attend to a patient's needs.
- Attend to the King's majesty.

with regards point 3. I think it should read:

**await her at the airport**